# iOS app with target set to iOS 13 does not provide older versions on App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios13

I have a new app that I released for App Store that has min target set to iOS 13.
In App Store Connect under Pricing and Availability->Last-Compatible Version Settings
it states
[image]

Clicking on add brings up this

[image]
So I would assume people with iOS 12 and below should have older versions of the app but this is not the case (I have tested).
When I go to the App Store with an iPhone 5 running iOS 12 the app does not appear.
Does anyone know how why and how I can fix this?

Comment: Sorry, but how does "I have a _new_ app that I released for App Store that has min target set to iOS 13" square with all those earlier versions? Surely this is an _old_ app and all you did was release a new _version_ of it?

Comment: So setting the iOS target to 13 makes this version of the app unavailable for users with iOS 12 or lower. It states in the first image "Some of your customers may not have a device that's compatible with your latest app version. To allow them to continue using your app, we make the last-compatible version of your app available to them". Now this is not the case for me (unless this only applies to people who already owns the app). The point is not the Business and Education but the Last-Compatible Version Settings.

Comment: It would probably help if you edited the screenshot to show the relevant section only.  Has the iTunes user you are using on the iPhone 5 previously purchased this app?  The last compatible version only applies to existing users, not new users. New users only have access to the latest version (or not at all if their device isn't compatible)

Comment: Yes its not an existing users so then thats why. Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Last compatible version" setting only applies to *existing customers*; i.e. People who have already purchased/downloaded your app.

They are able to continue to access the older version on devices that are not compatible with your latest version.

People who have never purchased your app before just won't see it in the store if their device isn't compatible.

If you release a version that requires iOS 13, your *new* customers will be running iOS 13 or later.

For reference, the *last compatible version* setting is described in the [App Store Connect help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/en.lproj/static.html#dev2db879917) (Emphasis mine)

> The versions of an app that are available for **existing customers** to download from iCloud. You need to exclude app versions from iCloud if the version includes legal or usability issues.

Comment: Today I release my app to store and it's required is 13 and up, so is there a way to change it to target 12 and up or something or apple will reject it?

Comment: You can release a new version that runs on more devices. That isn't a problem

Comment: But I guess the Apple store requires ios13+ to accept the app? Check this question I've faced before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658344/sdk-version-issue-when-upload-to-apple-store

Comment: You must build against the iOS 13 SDK (essentially use Xcode 11).  The SDK is independent of the targeted version.  Apple wants their users to be able to use their devices for as long as possible. They wouldn't prevent developers from releasing apps that run on older versions

Comment: Well, so should I change deployment target version let say to 12.0 and anyone has a 13+ the app will work with them right? And when do this thing will hinder me with Apple to approve the app?

Comment: You can change it without any problem from Apple.  You may need to change your code if you have used any pre-ios13 features, but Xcode will tell you about that.