# SDK version issue when upload to apple store?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, xcode11

I have Xcode 10.3 and I'm trying to upload my app to store but I got this error:

> SDK version issue, this app was built with ios 12.3 SDK new app for
>   iPhone must be built with ios 13 SDK

After researching I guess I should've updated Xcode to 11, but I can't right now.

So is there no other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why can't you update Xcode to 11?

Comment: @alexholstv It requires macOS 10.15.2 or later, and I have Mojave 10.14.6 -  'Hackintosh, it's hard to update as u know'

Comment: Hmm.. Really not sure if thats the case. Is there any particular reason you can't update to macOS 10.15.2?

Comment: @alexholstv I'm afraid to break it after upgrade to Catalina

Comment: Well, you can back up your project, update and try out your project. If I were really afraid I would install a virtual box, and try it on catalina to make sure nothing will happen. Not sure you can install vitrualbox on mac though.

Comment: I am suffering the same issue. Apple should have [extended the deadline for this to June 30th](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03262020b) but it appears they didn't bother to update the back end to actually implement it?! I have filed a bug on their [Feedback Assistant](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) - maybe you should do the same ?